# While printing data using fpdf library Data is not passing in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3, fpdf

I Have form in that i am displaying data.When I click on the print button I am going to save the data in pdf format for printing for that I am using FPDF Library.The problem is when i send the data from the controller to view only headers displaying like below But Data is not displaying.[image] I have written my view file like below.I have got stuck since yesterday.I Have getting the data in controller but not passing to the view.I can't understand why it is happening .The Way i am doing wrong or what please any help Would be Appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

### My controller Code

```
 public function printpage(){
                 $this->load->library('Myfpdf');
                 $data['result']=$this->Vendor_Model->displaydata();
                 if(!empty(array_filter($data))){
                  $this->load->view('Savedata',$data);
                 }else{
                 redirect('Vendorcontroller/showeditview');
                 }

                 }
```

### My Modal code for getting the data from the database

```
  public function displaydata(){
      $query=$this->db->query('SELECT `vndr_id`, s.state as state,`vndr_name`, `vndr_address`, `vndr_pincode`, `vndr_telephone`, `vndr_mobile`, `vndr_mailid`, `vndr_country`, `vndr_gsttin`, `vndr_cstno`, `vndr_totaldebit`, `vndr_totalcredit`, `vndr_bankname`, `vndr_acno`, `vndr_ifsccode` FROM `vendors` vndr INNER JOIN states s ON vndr_state=s.state_id order by vndr_id');
      if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query->result_array();
      }
    }
```

### My view code for print the data as pdf format

```
class printview extends FPDF
{
  function Header()
  {
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    $this->Cell(276,5,"VendorDetails",0,0,'C');
    $this->ln(15);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->Cell(55,10,"Name",1,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(90,10,"Address",1,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(50,10,"Telephone",1,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(70,10,"Email",1,0,'C');
    $this->ln();
  }
function Footer(){
$this->SetY(-15);
$this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
 $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}


function viewdata(){
if(isset($result)){
  foreach($result as $values){
  $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
  $this->Cell(55,10,$values['vndr_name'],1,0,'L');
  $this->Cell(90,10,$values['vndr_address'].','.$values['state'].'-'.$values['vndr_pincode'],1,0,'L');
  $this->Cell(50,10,$values['vndr_telephone'].','.$values['vndr_mobile'],1,0,'L');
  $this->Cell(70,10,$values['vndr_mailid'],1,0,'L');
  $this->ln();
}
}
}

}

$this->pdf = new Printview();
$this->pdf->SetMargins(15, 10, 20);
$this->pdf->AliasNbPages();
$this->pdf->AddPage('L','A4',0);
$this->pdf->viewdata();
$this->pdf->Output();
```

### This is Fdf library class

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class Myfpdf extends fpdf
{
function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  $ci=& get_instance();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass the `$result` data as a parameter :

```
$this->pdf->viewdata($result);
```

And also on the method :

```
function viewdata($result){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have changed this way it is working fine now.

```
   This is controller
   -------------------------
        public function printpage(){
                 $this->load->library('Myfpdf');
                 $data['result']=$this->Vendor_Model->displaydata();
                 if(!empty(array_filter($data))){
                  $this->load->view('Savedata',$data);
                 }else{
                 redirect('Vendorcontroller/showeditview');
                 }

                 }
```

### This is view file

```
function viewdata($result){
if(isset($result)){
  foreach($result as $values){
  $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
  $this->Cell(55,10,$values['vndr_name'],1,0,'L');
  $this->Cell(90,10,$values['vndr_address'].','.$values['state'].'-'.$values['vndr_pincode'],1,0,'L');
  $this->Cell(50,10,$values['vndr_telephone'].','.$values['vndr_mobile'],1,0,'L');
  $this->Cell(70,10,$values['vndr_mailid'],1,0,'L');
  $this->ln();
}
}
}

}

$this->pdf = new Printview();
$this->pdf->SetMargins(15, 10, 20);
$this->pdf->AliasNbPages();
$this->pdf->AddPage('L','A4',0);
$this->pdf->viewdata($result);
$this->pdf->Output();
```